# How can I copy tables between word documents without having the format change?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have two both word 2007 documents, A and B.

I want to copy a table from A to B, and that table's format is totally the same as I see in A, not automatically changing the format to B's template format.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of pasting regularly, use the "keep source formatting option." To find it, right click, and then under paste, it should be the first box.

Comment: I can't find "keep source formatting option". What you mean is ctrl+alt+v? I have tried every options(5 options),and no one works.

Comment: @sam what version of word are you using?

Comment: try paste special -> keep source formatting......you cannot preserve the margins though if that's something you want..

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is the width of the table, try copying the table.  If it is too big, right click on the small box to the upper left of the table.  Click on "table properties" and then set the preferred width to match the width of the page in the file that you are copying the file into.

Answer (score 0):

using "keep source formatting" didn't work for me.
My table still ran off the page when i pasted it from one Word document to another.
So what I did to resolve the situation is that I temporarily made the second Word document (the document in which the table was being pasted) a landscape document. 
That way, I was able to manipulate the table width down to something more manageable.
once i reformatted that second document back into letter, then my table fit properly.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the width of the table and it is too big, right click on the small box to the upper left of the table. Click on "Auto Fit" and choose "Auto fit to window"

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score -1):

Tables in Word:Mac

The only way it can be done is to recreate the table from scratch on your Mac version of Word otherwise it simply will not work. Forget 'table properties' and 'smart formatting'. It doesn't work. If your table isn't complicated, do it again otherwise get the person that sent you it to send it again in Excel. I have scoured the internet to no avail. That is the only way I've been able to get through this document I'm working on now.

Changing to landscape didn't work either. As soon as you put it back to portrait, it all goes wrong again. This is obviously a bug.